# Custom CSS on Blazor Built-In Component

Tags: css, blazor, blazor-webassembly

Whenever I use a css-class or css-id on a blazor builtin component like `InputText` the css won't be inherited by the component, or the component just overrides it. also the !important keyword in css doesn't help. Note that I need a solution that works with the builtin component.

Index.razor:

```
...
<InputText @bind-Value="FormData.Imei" id="text-in"/>
...
```

Index.razor.css:

```
#text-in {
   color: fuchsia !important;
   border: none;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`InputText` is a child component of `Index`. To apply style to child components you have to add `::deep` before a css selector. More details [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/components/css-isolation?view=aspnetcore-6.0#child-component-support). This should work:

```css
::deep #text-in {
   color: fuchsia !important;
   border: none;
}
```

It's also important to have a root element in parent component. The component's scope identifier is applied to the root element and other elements when the component is rendered.

Example from docs:

- Parent.razor

```
<div>
    <h1>Parent component</h1>

    <Child />
</div>
```

- Parent.razor.css

```
::deep h1 { 
    color: red;
}
```

- Child.razor

```
<h1>Child Component</h1>
```

Without the `<div>` in Parent.razor the `<h1>` element in Child component doesn't inherit Parent's component style.

Rendered Parent component and css selector:

```
<div b-edlqfbffve="">
    <h1 b-edlqfbffve="">Parent component</h1>
    <h1>Child Component</h1>
</div>

/* /Shared/Parent.razor.rz.scp.css */
[b-edlqfbffve] h1 {
    color: red;
}
```

Without the `::deep` combinator the css looks like this:

```
/* /Shared/Parent.razor.rz.scp.css */
h1[b-edlqfbffve] {
    color: red;
}
```